# Не правильно удаляются элементы массива

Tags: массивы

**Условие задачи:**   *Дан массив а1,...,а50. Найти  в нем последовательности из идущих подряд трех равных между собой элементов, и удалить два из них. Если таких нет напечатать  0.* 
Не могу понять, что я задал неправильно: нахождение 3-го повторяющегося элемента или удаление двух элементов из найденной последовательности, а может и то, и другое. Помогите разобраться. Заранее благодарен.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

   void main()
 {
   int i,j,k,f,n,count;
   int a[50];
   printf("\nVvedite kolichestvo elementov massiva n:\n");
   scanf("%d", &n);
   printf("Vvedite elementy massiva a:\n");
   for(i=0;i<n;i++)
   scanf("%d",&a[i]);
   f=0;
   count=0;
   for(i=0;i<n;i++)
   {
       for(j=i+1;j<n;j++)
       {
           if(a[i]==a[j])
           count++;

        }
       if(count==3){
       for(k=i;k<n-2;k++)
       {
           a[k]=a[k+2];
           n=n-2;
           f=1;
       }
    }
    }
   if(f==1){
   printf("Vvedenyi massiv imeet vid:\n");
   for(i=0;i<n;i++)
   printf("%d",a[i]);
   }
   else printf("\n 0\n");
```

}

Comment: @Антон123, наверное вместо 

    for (i = 0; i < n; i++)

достаточно

    for (i = 0; i < n-2; i++)

и тогда вместо цикла по j от i+1 до n достаточно "заглянуть" на 2 шага вперед

    if (a[i] == a[i+1] && a[i] == a[i+2]) { 
       // сдвигаем влево и уменьшаем n на 2.
       ...
    }

А вот тут надо понять, увеличивать или нет i (после сдвига) для следующего шага цикла по i. 

Т.е. во что должна превратится (из условия задачи не ясно) такая последовательность:

    1 1 1 1 1 

в

    1

или

    1 1 1



???

Comment: Скорее всего в 1.

Comment: Тогда после сдвига влево (тут `n` изменится) оставьте индекс на старом месте (вычитайте из него 1, т.к. в конце `for` добавится единичка).

Answer (score 1):

Вам нужно найти три *подряд идущих* равных элемента, а вы ищете просто три равных элемента. Внутренний цикл по `j` считает количество элементов, равных `a[i]`, от позиции `i + 1` до `n`, а надо бы до `i + 2`. (Обратите внимание на случай, когда `i + 2 >= n`!)

Возможно, есть ещё ошибки, после цикла по `j` дальше не читал.